# AEM and customized emails

Tags: email, aem

As quite well known, MCM (Market Campaign Management being part of AEM) allows to configure and manage emails. An important problem and potential fix has been discussed already in [this](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__bwrz-please_findsomemcm.html) thread.

Apart from the (rather technical) related issue, we have a functional related question.

Functionality we would like to implement covers:

- i18n of email content
- email related reporting (read emails vs bounced emails and this by country, language, segment ...)
- configuration of email batches
- configuration of attachments
- and an absolute must have .... the customization of the email content (by using different fonts and HTML tags)

I cannot find any references/examples supporting this functionality. Adobe's Email Channel (part of Marketing Cloud) seems to support part of this functionality (documented in [this](https://support.neolane.net/doc/AC6.1/en/DLV_Creating_deliveries_Advanced_options.html) article) and as well known, 3rd party solutions like MailChimp are a valid alternative but it's the preference of our customer to have most of the functionality within AEM.

Pointers to the customization of email content (the must have requirement) are very much appreciated. If one is inclined to believe our requirement is too specific to be handled by a (generic) WCM, don't hesitate to inform us accordingly.

many thanks in advance,

Wim

Comment: I think this is fine if old question. Adobe clear wants to push customers into the additionally licensed Adobe Campaign product. But for simple use-cases, it should be possible to send emails using the builtin MCM functionality of AEM. Doing so is possible but rather a pain. Here's a useful link I came across in this effort http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/tag/newsletter/

Answer (score 0):

Did you see AEM (CQ) - Adobe Campaign integration? I think that the solution should fit your needs. http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/solutions/campaign/pdfs/adobe-campaign-aem-solution-overview-ue.pdf

Comment: Hi, 

thanks for the feedback but I'm rather inclined to identify the content of the (2 pager) PDF as the usual semi-commercial bladibla.  Once again, a newsletter isn't a very recent concept (I remember I was experimenting with Word in 1998) and in the ideal world one would be able to recuperate (marketing or event  related) content data from other systems (by example internal or external databases) and enrich it afterwards and I'm still struggling to figure out which product in the Adobe stack would offer this type of functionality.    

but thanks anyhow,
Wim

Comment: so just investigate more about AEM with Adobe Campaign - it's a quite new integration but as far as I know it could cover your requirements. Or maybe contact Adobe sales rep? The PDF was supposed to point you to given pair of solutions not to give a full tech spec. Note that the next, more powerful release of this integration should be available at the end of this month.